# Нужен ли мягкий знак в слове "нравит(ь)ся"?

Tags: орфография

Но тебе продолжает нравит(ь)ся то падать, то парить.

Answer (score 2):

Но тебе **продолжает нравиться то падать, то парить.**

1) Это безличное предложение, предикативная основа включает только сказуемое.

2) Сказуемое **осложненное составное глагольное.** В этом случае **вспомогательная** часть состоит из двух глаголов, а  глагол в третьей позиции является **основным.**

Образцы подобных сказуемых: *хотел начать работать, хочет продолжить учиться.*

3) Но здесь основная часть ***то падать, то парить*** состоит из двух  глаголов, связанных союзом ***то...то*** (между ними однородные отношения). Поэтому фактически здесь **два однородных сказуемых.**

4) Вспомогательная часть состоит из фазового глагола ***продолжает*** в личной форме и модального глагола ***нравиться*** в форме **инфинитива.**

5) Поэтому мягкий знак в глаголе пишется: **продолжает (что делать?) нравиться.**

6) Текстовый пример:

Кстати, и многим партийным функционерам нравилось и **продолжает нравиться быть вершителями** всех дел. [Александр Смирнов. Партийная дискуссия? Да, дискуссия! // «Горизонт», 1989]

Answer (score -2):

Образцы подобных сказуемых: хотел начать работать, хочет продолжить учиться.
(Это примеры в будущем времени.)

В вашем предложении — настоящее время: 
«Тебе продолжает нравится падать и парить».

Comment: Приведенные образцы - это дополнительная информация, помогающая понять структуру подобных сказуемых.  А структура такова: два вспомогательных глагола + основной глагол, причем в личной форме стоит первый вспомогательный глагол, например: продолжил, продолжает, продолжит. Итак, первый глагол может стоять в форме любого времени, но два других глагола - это инфинитивы. И как раз из этого следует, что мягкий знак в глаголе "нравится" пишется, а это есть ответ на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Могу привести такие примеры: Ребенок должен привыкать заниматься самостоятельно. Он начинает любить заниматься спортом. Глаголы во второй позиции  "привыкать, любить" стоят  в форме инфинитива, причем мягкий знак определяется ПО СЛУХУ. Надеюсь, что теперь тема Вам понятна. Но Вы можете задать другие дополнительные вопросы, если что-нибудь еще осталось неясным.